# jwt.decode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verify'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I can generate the token with the route api/token but I can't use it after. All was functional before, but now I have this error from django rest framework, and I don't know why.

```
    File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 497, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 414, in initial
    self.perform_authentication(request)
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 324, in perform_authentication
    request.user
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 227, in user
    self._authenticate()
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 380, in _authenticate
    user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self)
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/authentication.py", line 40, in authenticate
    validated_token = self.get_validated_token(raw_token)
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/authentication.py", line 94, in get_validated_token
    return AuthToken(raw_token)
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/tokens.py", line 43, in __init__
    self.payload = token_backend.decode(token, verify=verify)
  File "/home/mathieu/.local/share/virtualenvs/back-aSs_Rzmq/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework_simplejwt/backends.py", line 90, in decode
    return jwt.decode(
TypeError: decode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verify'
```

I follow the simple dango rest simple jwt example.

My settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
    ],
}
```

And my views.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer, UserRegistrationSerializer
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework import status
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist


class UserList(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self):
        users = User.objects.all().exclude(is_staff=True).order_by("id")
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserRegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class UserDetail(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @csrf_exempt
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    @csrf_exempt
    def get(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk=pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @csrf_exempt
    def put(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @csrf_exempt
    def patch(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    @csrf_exempt
    def delete(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        user.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Looks like the problem is straight from the django-rest-framework module or maybe my os with ssl problem.

Comment: I have the problem when I try to request API

Comment: That library always has the same problems

Answer (score 23):

Fixed the issue with PyJWT==2.1.0 and djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.8.0 in the requirements.txt:

```
PyJWT==2.1.0
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.8.0
```

It may be noted that PyJWT 2.2.0 (Released: Oct 7, 2021) is causing the error. So pinning PyJWT<2.2 or alternatively PyJWT==2.1.0 in personal projects is a workaround for now, but ideally this would be either pinned appropriately here:

https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/blob/master/setup.py#L59

or handled in source code.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is in pyJWT version. Try to downgrade it to 2.0.1.

Comment: https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/releases
Yesterday they release new 2.2.0 version, which is broken. 
I tested prev 2.1.0 - it works fine.

Comment: Confirming, that version `PyJWT==2.1.0` works!

Comment: I have PyJWT==2.1.0 but the error is still

Comment: Thanks, you saved me. For anyone who uses `pipenv` command will be `pipenv install "pyjwt~=2.1.0"`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is coming from new release 2.2.0 (see https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/issues/698)

Downgrading to pyjwt==2.1.0 will fix the issue.