# TypeError at /auth/jwt/refresh decode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verify' using Djoser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I have got this error while trying to refresh a JWT with [Djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jwt_endpoints.html) using the JWT endpoints. I need your help please.

I have followed all the settings as they are in the DOCS.

Comment: Check this stack overflow page. change the pyjwit version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69485121/django-rest-framework-simple-jwt-decode-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-v

Answer (score 0):

To Solve TypeError: decode() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verify' Error Latest release of PyJWT 2.2.0 has some issue. So that just downgrade PyJWT to 2.1.0 or 2.0.1 which is working fine. Or You can use PyJWT to 2.0.1 which is also working fine.